# I am trying to use openpyxl to remove the domain\ from a list of computer names

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an xlsx file that has a list of computer names that are in this format domain\computer name. I am trying to use openpyxl to remove the domain\ portion of the naming convention. The tricky part is that not all the domains are the same so I need a wild card or something that will identify them all. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
#Removing Domain\ from computer names
filename = r'C:\Users\user1\Documents\Quarter Report Scripts\client test\protection.xlsx'
excelFile = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet1 = excelFile.active
for row in sheet1.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1):
    for cell in row:
        if '*\\' in cell.value:
            cell.value = cell.value[7:] #This will replace the cell value with a trimmed string
#End domain\ removal
```

But this is the error I am getting
if '*\' in cell.value:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: You can only use `if in…` with some kind of sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import openpyxl

# Removing Domain\ from computer names
filename = r'C:\Users\user1\Documents\Quarter Report Scripts\client test\protection.xlsx'
excelFile = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet1 = excelFile.active
for row in sheet1.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1):
    for cell in row:
        cl = cell.value
        if cl is not None:
            cell.value = cl.split("\\")[-1]
excelFile.save(filename)
excelFile.close()
```